# Set top level directory to be handled by Perl?

Tags: apache-2.2, perl, httpd.conf, mod-perl

I have an Apache server set up to use mod_perl. I have it set up to handle all requests using a Perl module `MyModule`. Here is part of my `httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule perl_module modules/mod_perl.so

<Directory />    
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

PerlModule MyModule
<Location />
    SetHandler modperl
    PerlResponseHandler MyModule
</Location>
```

This seems to work fine, except top level directory (ie. www.mysite.com/) is not being sent to `MyModule`. What's going wrong?

Comment: Why all the close votes?

Comment: Please provide the full configuration. I suspect that another configuration is changing the behaviour for /.

Answer (score 1):

#### Option One

Specify a [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) which (a) is valid, and (b) is processed via mod_perl.

```
DirectoryIndex index.pl

# This part probably isn't necessary, but might help.
<Files *.pl>
  SetHandler modperl
  PerlResponseHandler MyHandler
</Files>
```

#### Option Two

Use a rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /somefile
```